# Processing a collection taking two adjacent elements at a time (use of stream)

Tags: java, list, java-stream, fold

I have a list of objects that represent different cities. What I want to do with that list is obtain the sum of the distance between adjacent cities in the list. So if my list is `l = {c1,c2,c3}`,the result would be
total `sum = distance(c1,c2) + distance(c2,c3)`.

I was trying to make use of the stream API but I couldn't find a way to process the elements on a list in this particular case where the processing is not one element at a time but involves two adjacent elements of the list at each step.

I would really appreciate if someone has any idea how to apply stream in this way, to give me a hand.

Comment: Did you write an imperative code for that? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am new to Java and I've been applying stream to lists but only processing one element at a time, now I want to use it but working with two (adjacent elements at a time) and I still couldn't find a way to do it

Comment: Double totalKm = new Double(0d);
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.size() - 1; i++) {
            totalKm += this.distanceBetweenCities(cities.get(i), cities.get(i + 1));
        }

Comment: That is my code up to now but I would like to use stream instead of iterating with for

Comment: This would be a poor use of DoubleStream.  You would need to use a field to “remember” the last value in the stream, but the Stream documentation explicitly recommends the stream operations be stateless.  You’re better off using a regular loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
double distance = IntStream.range(0, cities.size() - 1)
        .mapToDouble(i -> distance(cities.get(i), cities.get(i + 1)))
        .sum();
```

This creates an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and maps the calculated distance for the neighbor cities. At the end all distance are summed up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
n = l.size();
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
      .limit(n-1)
      .map( i -> distance(l.get(i), l.get(i+1))
      .reduce(0, (totalDistance, currDistance) -> totalDistance + currDistance, (distance1, distance2) -> distance1 + distance2);
```